# Stop /volume from increasing

Tags: discussion, tags

The tag [volume](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/volume) is ambiguous. It's used at least for:

- Sound volume, e.g. [1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/204782/pulseaudio-with-external-sound-adapter-work-around-broken-sound) [2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/204268/how-can-i-synchronise-kmix-and-alsamixer-volumes-at-maximum)
- Storage volumes, e.g. [1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/189054/how-to-obtain-info-about-physical-volume-as-non-root-user) [2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/166846/tar-using-progress-bar-and-handling-multi-volumes)

How should we disambiguate it?

Answer (score 23):

For generic storage topics, there's already [storage](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/storage) and [block-device](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/block-device). For specific types of volume, there's [lvm](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lvm), [device-mapper](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/device-mapper), etc. So I think we should just get rid of the uses of [volume](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/volume) for storage topics, by retagging to existing tags. Eyeballing it, that's maybe 15 questions to retag.

Once we've done that, we should rename [volume](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/volume) to something less ambiguous. I propose [sound-volume](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sound-volume) or [audio-volume](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/audio-volume) (perhaps both). “sound volume” wins [Google Books ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=audio+volume%2Csound+volume&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Caudio%20volume%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csound%20volume%3B%2Cc0), for what it's worth.

Comment: +1 for `sound-volume` if only because many users might start typing `sound` and so find it.